# java.lang.NumberFormatException: null at java.lang.Integer.parseInt

Tags: java, numberformatexception

Code in the below link: https://github.com/dheenupriya/Gpay

At first.. I login, then I get the mainPage.jsp and I click transactions and I can view transactions and click Main Page button and I move back to mainPage.jsp and then when I click logout in mainpage.jsp, I move to index.jsp. Now my problem is.. when I click back, i go to mainPage.jsp and from there when I click linkbankaccount.jsp, I able to go to session_expired.jsp as session==null... but when I click other links like view balance or transaction_history.jsp... I get HTTP 500 internal server error... don't know y...

**The page I get when I click logout and go back to mainpage and click linkbankaccount.jsp**
[image]

**The page I get when I click other links like transactions, view balance**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Because you have removed the `userId` after logged out.

**Logout .java Line#11**

`session.removeAttribute("userId");`

and then you got a `null` when you go back to histoy:

**Transaction_history.java Line#42**

`String s_user_id = (String)session.getAttribute("userId");`

Comment: I have a added a condition, if userId is null..I need to go back to session_expired page.. y didn't it check that condition....

Comment: Is there any other method to redirect the page to session_expired page if userId is null...